# Differentiate under integral sign-Leibniz Rule

Tags: calculus

I try to differenciate the following integral

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}f\left(c\left(s\right)\right)ds$

with respect to $c(x)$. $f$ is a function of $c(s)$ in which $s$ varies between $0$ and $t$.

I am not sure if I could use classical Leibniz rule because the term $c$ varies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Leibnitz's rule does not apply here.  But you may use the chain rule and write

$$\frac{dF}{dc}=\frac{dF}{dx} \frac{dx}{dc}=\frac{\frac{dF}{dx}}{\frac{dc}{dx}}=\frac{f\left(c(x)\right)}{\frac{dc}{dx}}$$